# Unknown Error (6c 15) with Setoutgoinglength in java card 2.2.1

Tags: javacard

I wrote a code that for java card 2.2.1 and I test it eith JCIDE.
I get error in method Setoutgoinglength()

```
    public void getoutput(APDU apdu)
{
     byte [] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     byte hello[] = {'H','E','L','L','O',' ','W','O','R','L','D',' ', 'J','A','V','A',' ','C','A','R','D'};
    short le = apdu.setOutgoing();
    short totalBytes = (short) hello.length;   
    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(hello, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short)totalBytes);

    apdu.setOutgoingLength(totalBytes);
    apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) hello.length);}
```

Comment: Can you post the APDU you sent?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I send "00 40 00  00 00" my ins=40 and lc=00

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I just want to point out that the last byte in your APDU is considered an Le and not an Lc. Lc is only present when command data field is present. Otherwise, the fifth byte will be treated as an Le.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`6CXX` means that your Le is not equal to the correct length of response data (XX is equal to the length of correct response data). `6C15` specifically means that the correct Le to be used should be `0x15`.

What happened is that your Le field is `0x00` (which is actually interpreted by the card as 256 in decimal form) but you used `totalBytes`, which has a value of `0x15`, as parameter to `apdu.setOutgoingLength()` which is not equal to 256.

The correct APDU to send is `00 40 00 00 15`

Comment: Thank you for help but in this sample it is simple but another samples may be difficault. How can I calculate answer length? I want to execute getoutput() I don't know answer length.

Comment: How to send apdu from my host? Alway I should know response length?

Comment: @FatemeJafari It is pretty easy: just wait for 6CXX and response with Le=XX. You cannot know the correct Le before card tells it, of course.

Comment: It's means : Always when I want to call this method I should call twice. in first call I can get le and second call I can get my response . Is it correct?

Comment: This is wrong behaviour according to ISO7816-4: "If the Le field contains only bytes set to '00', then all the bytes until the end of the file should be read within the limit of 256 for a short Le field, or 65 536 for an extended Le field." You do not need know the length of the data, thats what Le=00 is there for. What kind of card are you using? Is it using protocol T=0/1/CL?

Comment: This behavior is completely normal for T=0 protocol according to ISO7816-3. This behavior applies on cases 2 and 4 APDUs only. According to ISO7816-3, when this happens, the card must be ready to receive the same command TPDU with P3 (Le field) = previous SW2 (second byte of the returned status word of the previous command).

Comment: I test it in Jcide environment.  and T=0 and use simulator